# InDesign Data Merge: multiple records per page

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm new to Adobe InDesign user and I'd like to create multiple coupons printed on a A4 page, each of them having a different coupon code.

I understand that I need to use Data Merge, but unfortunately, when asking to have Multiple Records Per Page, only the text box that contains the variable coupon code gets duplicated on the page (all other pictures remain only in the original coupon).

See screenshot without multiple records per page:
[image]

And screenshot with multiple records per page (only the textbox with green text content gets duplicated):
[image]

Any hint on what I'm doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated !
Many thanks,
Tom

Comment: From your screenshots I see that you had the image in the Master Page -A-! You need to have the image on Page1!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in InDesign. I've spent 10+ hours trying to get it to work. It doesn't work. Eventually I had to data merge a 1up document (size of one item, not the whole page). Then I had to use Quite Imposing plugin to Acrobat to impose them into a Letter size sheet (US sizes for me).

Hope that helps.